# Why is div's jQuery position() 0,0 after onload but moments later is the real value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

**Dang, I figured it out...  [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509637/636189). The div layer I was querying was hidden via CSS then revealed in JS after my position query.  Since I never saw it hidden I didn't realize it was, and that's why jQuery returned 0,0.**

I feel like an idiot.

The code below was just meant to be illustrative and included all the code I thought was necessary, but it left out a critical CSS definition and a critical JS call:

I've got a div layer with some sub-div layers for menu items.

```
<div id="menuItems">
    <div id="menuItem0">Menu Item 0</div>
    <div id="menuItem1">Menu Item 1</div>
</div>
```

The position and dimensions are defined in an external CSS.

```
#menuItem0 { top: 0px; left: 100px; height: 40px; width: 200px; background-color: green;}
#menuItem1 { top: 0px; left: 350px; height: 40px; width: 200px; background-color: red;}
```

And on load the script is supposed to show the positions and dimensions of the menu items:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    prepareMenuItems();    
});

function prepareMenuItems() { 
    var numberOfMenuItems = $("#menuItems").children().length;

    for (var i=0; i<numberOfMenuItems; i++) {
        console.log("left: "+$("#menuItem" + i).position().left + 
            " top:" + $("#menuItem" + i).position().top +
            " w:" + $("#menuItem" + i).width() + 
            " h:"+ $("#menuItem" + i).height());
    }
}
```

In my live demo what I see in Google Chrome (latest) is:
left: 0 top: 0 w: 200 h: 40
left: 0 top: 0 w: 200 h: 40

The left and top are ZERO when they should not be.

If I force a break once the page has loaded and had a moment the Chrome debugger will evaluate a watch on $("#menuItem0").position().left properly.  But why doesn't it on load?  It spits out the right width and height, so the CSS has clearly been loaded.  And it knows the answers later since a forced break gives the right answer so this isn't me looking at the wrong thing's position.

Help!  It's driving me mad.

(Sorry about the earlier typos I was trying to be illustrative rather than literal and I didn't realize people would test the given code.  [Magritte did so via Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508440/636189) and the code works as expected, so it must have something to do with external references to the CSS or JS or something...).

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  You have typos.  I fixed them and turned your example into a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wBqT6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...  I was an idiot...   I didn't realize one of the CSS rules was making a parent div hidden at the start and code milliseconds later would make it visible.  So at the time jQuery was querying it for position the layer was hidden and jQuery's behavior is (I didn't realize) to return 0 when a div is hidden.  Milliseconds later the layer is shown and now on break the jQuery worked as expected.  The secret was, of course, to not have that parent div layer hidden at the start.

Thank you to you guys who responded.  You guys were awesome to look at it, fix my stupid typos, and force me to look further into it to make a working demo to better prove my point (which led me to the solution).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me, you have a few typos: http://jsfiddle.net/MQfqA/1/

```
function prepareMenuItems() { 
    var numberOfMenuItems = $("#menuItems").children().length;

    for (var i=0; i<numberOfMenuItems; i++) {
        console.log("left: "+$("#menuItem" + i).position().left + 
            " top:" + $("#menuItem" + i).position().top +
            " w:" + $("#menuItem" + i).width() + 
            " h:"+ $("#menuItem" + i).height());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax was wrong. This now works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    prepareMenuItems();    
});

function prepareMenuItems() { 
    var numberOfMenuItems = $("#menuItems").children().length;

    for (var i=0; i<numberOfMenuItems; i++) {
        console.log("left: "+$("#menuItem" + i).position().left + 
            " top:"+$("#menuItem" + i).position().top+
            " w:"+$("#menuItem" + i).width() + 
            " h:"+ $("#menuItem" + i).height());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My impression or did you forget to close a quotation on line 11?